# Array is not populating the first record

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this array populating from mysql. But it is not showing me the first record. I can't figure out what the problem is. It should be simple. Here is the code.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT user_instance.instance_name, user_instance.host_name FROM       
dba_account, user_instance WHERE dba_account.account_id = user_instance.account_id AND 
dba_account.account_id = '1'");
echo mysql_error();
$nume = mysql_fetch_row($result);
while($note = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='instance_name' class='instance_name'
    disabled='disabled' value='$note[instance_name]' size='25' /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='host_name' class='host_name' disabled='disabled' 
    value='$note[host_name]' size='25' /></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: get rid of `$nume = mysql_fetch_row($result);`

Comment: Which array is causing problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're fetching the first row in $nume = mysql_fetch_row. That pulls the first record. Then you're iterating through the rest of the records in your while loop. Remove that first line.

Comment: Yes. But i just posted it so it's telling me to wait for 10 minutes. After that I will. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The first time you call `mysql_fetch_row()`, it advances the result resource pointer to the second result.  Don't do that. Especially considering you are not using the variable `$nume` in your loop in any way, it is unnecessary and harmful to your logic.

```
// Don't do this!
//$nume = mysql_fetch_row($result);

// Instead just fetch the loop
while($note = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   // etc...
}
```